# SQL Server 2016 access other table values before Insert into

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Is it possible to do a **`JOIN ON xx.xx = xx.xx`** before I do the **`insert into`** query?

The data I have coming into my stored procedure is this (`@val1`):

```
network,type,incrementRelease,environment,serviceManagerType,
serviceManagerSubType,description,manufacturer,vendor
```

And the values for above (`@val2`):

```
'Force','SW','3','ATT','STORAGE','CHASSIS','details here','Microsoft','REDHAT'
```

And now the Query (stored procedure) itself:

```
INSERT INTO mLine 
   (@val1) 
VALUES 
   (@val2)
```

Now the reason why I need to call a `JOIN ON` before I do an insert is that currently the **`environment, serviceManagerType, serviceManagerSubType, manufacturer`** and **`vendor`** should all have a number associated with the value that it currently has in my insert query.

So in other words:

```
mLine table:
id  |network |type |....|environment |...
-----------------------------------------
54  |Force   |SW   |....|ATT         |...

environment table:
id |Name
-------- 
1  |Open
2  |Closed
3  |ATT
4  |Unknown
5  |Other
```

For the example above, **`environment`** is being sent with a value of **`ATT`** but in the table **`mLine`** its a number which should be **`3`**.

```
mLine table:
id  |network |type |....|environment |...
-----------------------------------------
54  |Force   |SW   |....|3           |...
```

What all would I have to modify in my stored procedure in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes this is not a big deal at all. You would use your select statement as the values.

Comment: If you can share some details about what you are actually doing here it would really help. At the very least the current code you are using.

Comment: AFAIK, If you have only `@val1` and `@val2` then you can't do it as you asked!? ;).

Comment: It seems a strange way to provide data to an SP. Do you know in advance what is going to be in the `@Val1` list? How is the field list validated? In any case you can't supply a field list in a variable to INSERT. I can't see how this would ever work. I agree with @shA.t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to fully parameterize you query and select from you environment table for you Id value.

```
INSERT INTO mLine(Network, type, incrementRelease, environment, serviceManagerType, serviceManagerSubType, description, manufacturer, vendor)
SELECT @Network, @type, @incrementRelease, E.ID, @serviceManagerType, @serviceManagerSubType, @description, @manufacturer, @vendor
FROM dbo.environment E
WHERE E.Name = @environment;
```

edit: updated answer based on comments.

Comment: But I only have **@val1** and **@val2** to work with. In order to do what you and Marc are saying then wouldn't I need to have it sent individually in order to break it down to 1 value and 1 name at a time?

Comment: The better way to do what you want is to do a fully parameterized query.
`code`
INSERT INTO mLine(Network,type,incrementRelease,environment,serviceManagerType,serviceManagerSubType,description,manufacturer,vendor)
SELECT @Network, @type, @incrementRelease, E.ID, @serviceManagerType, @serviceManagerSubType, @description, @manufacturer, @vendor
FROM dbo.environment E
WHERE E.Name = @environment;

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can feed the insert statement with a select (where you build the joins you need) instead of fixed values.

Instead of

```
INSERT INTO mLine (field list) 
VALUES (values list)
```

Do :

```
INSERT INTO mLine (environment)
SELECT id FROM environment WHERE Name = @environment
```

The SELECT can be as complex as you need it, in order to retrieve data from multiple tables.

Updated : Considering that you don't have the @environment value, because it's packed on the @val2 parameter, you will first need to unpack that parameter, extracting each individual value. You can do so using the STRING_SPLIT function.

```
declare @network varchar(20);
declare @type varchar(20);
declare @incrementRelease varchar(20);
declare @environment varchar(20);

select @network = value from string_split(@val2, ',') fetch next 1 row only;
select @type = value from string_split(@val2, ',') offset 1 rows fetch next 1 row only;
select @incrementRelease = value from string_split(@val2, ',') offset 2 rows fetch next 1 row only;
select @environment = value from string_split(@val2, ',') offset 3 rows fetch next 1 row only;
```

Comment: Well I am not able to edit the way the data is coming into the stored procedure.... so I don't think I can do it that way?

Comment: I see. You need first to split @val2 using the STRING_SPLIT function, in order to have the components needed for that SELECT.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how to extract all the information that you need from @val2

Comment: I'm getting "fetch" errors with this: **Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 20
Invalid usage of the option next in the FETCH statement.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near '1'...etc etc**

Comment: How about I create a **temp table** and place all those values into it and then do a **select/join on** on that and return?